# Form Text Field Update

Tags: reactjs, forms

Working through my first ReactJS project which displays data pulled from an API (Django Rest Framework). On the homepage, there is a list of movies that is displayed with edit/delete icons:

```
function MovieList(props){

  const movieClicked = movie => evt => {
    props.movieClicked(movie)
  }
  
  const editClicked = movie => evt => {
    props.editClicked(movie)
    console.log(`You are now editing: ${movie.title}`)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      { props.movies && props.movies.map( movie => {
        return (
          <div key={movie.id} className="movie-item">
            <h2 onClick={movieClicked(movie)}>{ movie.title }</h2>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit} onClick={editClicked(movie)}/>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}/>
          </div>
        )
      }) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

The `editClicked` functions triggers a form to display that has pre-filled the `title` and `description` fields with data from the API.

```
function MovieForm(props) {

  const [ title , setTitle ] = useState(props.movie.title);
  const [ description , setDescription ] = useState(props.movie.description);

  console.log(title);

  const updateClicked = () => {
    API.updateMovie(props.movie.id, {title, description})
    .then( resp => props.updatedMovie(resp) )
    .catch( err => console.log(err) )
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      { props.movie ? (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="title">Title</label><br/>
          <input id="title" type="text" placeholder="title" value={ title } 
              onChange={ evt => {setTitle(evt.target.value);
                console.log(evt.target.value);} }
          /><br/>
          <label htmlFor="description">Description</label><br/>
          <textarea id="description" type="text" placeholder="description" value={description}
              onChange={ evt => setDescription(evt.target.value)}
          ></textarea><br/>
          <button onClick={updateClicked}>Update</button>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Here is how each component is displayed in `App.js`

```
function App() {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [selectedMovie, setSelectedMovie] = useState(null);
  const [editedMovie, setEditedMovie] = useState(null);

  useEffect( () => {
      fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/", { 
        method : 'GET',
        headers : {
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
          'Authorization' : 'Token a4db63b236737f5d5fe06163a57b83a797ab55e7'
        }
       })
       .then( resp => resp.json())
       .then( resp => setMovies(resp))
       .catch( err => console.log(err))
  }, [] )


  const loadMovie = movie => {
    setSelectedMovie(movie);
    setEditedMovie(null);
  }

  const editClicked = movie => {
    setEditedMovie(movie);
    setSelectedMovie(null);
  }

  const updatedMovie = movie => {
    const newMovies = movies.map( mov => {
      if (mov.id === movie.id) {
        return movie;
      }
      return mov;
    })
    setMovies(newMovies)
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>MOVIE RATING APP</h1>
      </header>
      <div className="layout">
          <MovieList movies={movies} movieClicked={loadMovie} editClicked={editClicked}/>
          <MovieDetails movie={selectedMovie} updateMovie={loadMovie}/>
          { editedMovie ? <MovieForm movie={editedMovie} updatedMovie={updatedMovie}/> : null }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When a first edit icon is selected, the forms display as expected and I can edit fields, update, and see resulting changes in the front-end and database. The bug I'm experiencing is that when a second icon is selected, the form does not update leading the user to believe they are still editing the same entry, although the form is pointing to whatever new movie/description was clicked.

**How might I get the form to update when another edit icon is selected**? I suppose another workaround for this issue is to have the edit form display and not allow the user to select another movie for updating until the current edit is closed (update or cancelled). Thanks for your suggestions and let me know if you need to see more code!

Here's a screenshot of the webpage I'm talking about:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hey , can you please upload the screenshot of you page so that we will get the clear idea exactly want you want.

Comment: Updated in the post - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is that the **MovieForm** component **is not re-initialized** when switching between different movies, **it only gets re-rendered**. This means that `useState` value in **MovieForm** doesn't change (note that the value you pass to `useState` serves as initial value only). So for the next render the state keeps its old value.

One simple solution is to have an effect which sets the state when the movie prop changes in **MovieForm**.
I've created a working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-moore-wjz16). Of course, it can be further optimized by batching state updates to avoid multiple re-renders when setting the values, but I think it shows where the problem lies.

Also I noticed you're using a hardcoded id for inputs, not sure if this causes a problem, but I added the html id of the movie to the html id attribute of the inputs to make them unique per movie.

Comment: Solved! Thanks for your detailed response :)